# Using streams to find Max

Tags: java, java-stream

Is the following the recommended way to attempt finding Max with streams?

```
List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();
emps.add(new Employee("Roy1",32));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy2",12));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy3",22));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy4",42));
emps.add(new Employee("Roy5",52));

Integer maxSal= emps.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getSalary()).reduce((a,b)->Math.max(a, b));
System.out.println("Max " + maxSal);
```

It results in a compilation error - what does this mean?

```
error: incompatible types: OptionalInt cannot be
nverted to Integer
                  Integer maxSal= emps.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getSalary()).
uce((a,b)->Math.max(a, b));
```

Comment: Streams uses OptionalInt, which is an Integer that COULD contain an Int value. I don’t think optionals can be « mapped » as the outcome could be unpredictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your question the problem is that `reduce` method is going to return an `OptionalInt` so you need to call the `.getAsInt()` method if you want to have the Integer value.

```
    Integer maxSal = emps.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.getSalary())
         .reduce((a,b)->Math.max(a, b)).getAsInt();
```

In case there is no maximum on the list you will get a `NoSuchElementException` that you need to deal with.

Comment: `getAsInt()` should not be used, there are better ways

Comment: There is no reason to box the `int` to an `Integer`, so the declaration should be `int maxSal`…

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `Integer.min` in reduce which returns `OptionalInt`, can be used to get `Int` (make sure the boundary checks)

using `IntStream`

```
int max1 = emps.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).max().getAsInt();
```

using `IntSummaryStatistics` [if you are interested in statistics, like min, max, avg]

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = emps.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).summaryStatistics();
int max2 = stats.getMax();
```

`reduce` function

```
int max3 = emps.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).reduce(Integer::min).getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you *might* shorten your `emps` initialization with`Arrays.asList(T...)` like

```
List<Employee> emps = Arrays.asList(new Employee("Roy1", 32), 
        new Employee("Roy2", 12), new Employee("Roy3", 22),
        new Employee("Roy4", 42), new Employee("Roy5", 52));
```

Next, you can use [`OptionalInt.orElseThrow(Supplier<X>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) which will get the `max` value from the `List` **or** throw a `RuntimeException`

```
int maxSal = emps.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).max()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No Such Element"));
System.out.println("Max " + maxSal);
```

Finally, you *could* also reason that no one would accept a negative salary, and use [`orElse(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElse-int-) like

```
int maxSal = emps.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).max().orElse(-1);
System.out.println("Max " + maxSal);
```

Comment: Hi! I don't see the benefit of using `orElseThrow` to throw a `RuntimeException` with the same message as the `NoSuchElementException` exception that would be thrown if you used `getAsInt()`. (And I'm not saying that the message is wrong).

Answer (score -1):

There is already a `max` method in `IntStream`. You don't have to reinvent the wheel:

```
OptionalInt maxSal = emps.stream().mapToInt(Employee::getSalary).max();
System.out.println("Max " + maxSal);
```

`max` returns `OptionalInt` instead of `Integer` because there can be no elements in the list. You can use `OptionalInt` methods to extract the value from it:

```
maxSal.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Or:

```
System.out.println(maxSal.orElse(0));
```

Or:

```
System.out.println(maxSal.getAsInt());
```

The latter one may throw an exception, so be careful.